# Using GMavenPlus to run spock groovy tests alongside java junit tests from maven surefire

Tags: maven, groovy, spock, maven-surefire-plugin, gmavenplus

I am trying to run "spock groovy tests alongside java junit tests from maven surefire"

I followed the examples

- https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki/Examples#joint-compilation &
- https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki/Usage#configuring-gmavenplus-1

When I have the gmavenplus + groovy plugins defined in the pom, the groovy test runs but not the java test.

When I have the gmavenplus + groovy plugins removed from the pom, the java test runs but not the groovy test.

The files I have are

- src/main/java/org/gw/JavaClass.java

  ```
   package org.gw;

   public class JavaClass {
   }
  ```
- src/test/java/org/gw/JavaTest.java

  ```
   package org.gw;

   import org.junit.Test;

   public class JavaTest {

       @Test
       public void testMethod1() {
           System.out.println("testMethod1");
       }
   }
  ```
- src/test/groovy/org/gw/GroovyTest.groovy

  ```
   package org.gw
   import spock.lang.Specification
   import spock.lang.Unroll

   @Unroll
   class GroovyTest extends Specification {

       def 'do a spock test'() {
           when:
           def doa = "spock test"

           then:
           println("done a " + doa)
       }
   }
  ```
- pom.xml

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

       <groupId>org.gw</groupId>
       <artifactId>mcve</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

       <properties>
           <groovy.version>3.0.3</groovy.version>
       </properties>

       <dependencies>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>junit</groupId>
               <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
               <version>4.13</version>
               <scope>test</scope>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
               <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
               <version>${groovy.version}</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
               <version>2.0-M3-groovy-3.0</version>
           </dependency>

       </dependencies>

       <build>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <!-- The gmavenplus plugin is used to compile Groovy code. To learn more about this plugin,
                   visit https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki -->
                   <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                   <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>1.10.0</version>
                   <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>addSources</goal>
                               <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                               <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                               <goal>compile</goal>
                               <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                               <goal>compileTests</goal>
                               <goal>removeStubs</goal>
                               <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                           </goals>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
               </plugin>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.8.1</version>
               </plugin>
               <plugin>
                   <!-- if including source jars, use the no-fork goals
                        otherwise both the Groovy sources and Java stub sources
                        will get included in your jar -->
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                   <!-- source plugin \> = 2.1 is required to use the no-fork goals -->
                   <version>3.2.1</version>
                   <executions>
                       <execution>
                           <id>attach-sources</id>
                           <goals>
                               <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                               <goal>test-jar-no-fork</goal>
                           </goals>
                       </execution>
                   </executions>
               </plugin>

               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
               </plugin>

           </plugins>
       </build>
   </project>
  ```
- My Output is

  ```
   [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ mcve ---
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO]  T E S T S
   [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Running org.gw.GroovyTest
   done a spock test
   [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.164 s - in org.gw.GroovyTest
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] Results:
   [INFO] 
   [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
  ```

Comment: As suggested by Keegan, the associated question does answer the question.

And to clarify Spock 2 need Junit5 and adding the vintage engine allowed my Junit4 tests to compile and run.

Comment: You will need to configure your maven-surefire-plugin to include both files. In my example all the groovy test files end with Spec.groovy and junit test ends with Test.java.

<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>